# What article should be used when talking about a job/profession in general?

Tags: articles

For example, "The most difficult job is a/the/_ doctor". What article (if any) should be used here?

Comment: For roles and offices, a bare role NP will do, so no determiner required.

Comment: 'The most difficult job is that of the doctor' is perhaps better.

Comment: Or maybe "The most difficult job is 'Doctor'."

Comment: Uh… No. Sorry but this has no place here. It is at best a Question for English Language Learners. –